# Delegating host names / sub-domain management to another DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

we have created a domain (let's say MyDomain.com) with GoogleApps so it's now hosted by eNom DNS servers.

Since all our servers are hosted on amazon cloud we want to use Amazon DNS service (Called Route53) to manage all host names (example server123.MyDomain.com).

Is it possible to configure eNom DNS by adding some records to delegate hostnames (or subdomain) management to another DNS, in this case Amazon DNS ?

Thanks!

Med

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really delegate individual hostnames without delegating them as individual zones, and you probably don't want to do that because it is a giant pain to manage.

Rather, create a single zone which can be delegated to your other DNS service.  In your zone for mydomain.com hosted at eNom, add the delegation:

```
servers.mydomain.com   IN   NS   ns-123.awsdns-12.com
                       IN   NS   ns-456.awsdns-45.com
```

Substitute your assigned servers from Amazon accordingly.  This will create a new zone delegation for servers.mydomain.com pointing to the Amazon service.

Then, following the Amazon instructions, create your A records in the new zone in XML.

```
...
<Name>server123.servers.mydomain.com</Name>
<Type>A</Type>
...
<ResourceRecord>
  <Value>12.34.56.78</Value>
</ResourceRecord>
...
etc.
```

See the [Route 53](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/GettingStartedGuide/) reference for details on that.

Comment: Hi @PapelPincel, I am curious if you managed to configure as above in `enom.com`? I find no way to create NS records with them.

Comment: Hi @Yonatan, sorry I don't remember how I did it, It's been more than three years now and I've left the company since then.